# scale around certain point over time SpriteKit

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I have a SpriteKit Scene in which I want to have the effect as if a camera zoom and scale. Does anyone know of any libraries or some easy methods of doing this?

It was very easy to do in other 2D engines but does not seem simple.

I was thinking of doing it from the app delegate, and using the window to zoom since my character does stay around the same position.

The desired effect I would like to accomplish is like that of the start of an Angry Bird level when the camera pans into the level and then the launch doc.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_iQbZ3KNGWQ This is an example of the camera zoom and pans I am talking about.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add an `SKNode` to the `SKScene`, and make your scene content children of that node instead of direct children of the scene, then you can zoom and pan all of the contained content just by adjusting the `xScale`, `yScale` and `position` properties of the added node. (Any content you did not want scrolled e.g. scores or whatever could then be added to a different `SKNode` or added directly to the scene).

The adjustment could be done by overriding one of `update:`, `didEvaluateActions`, or `didSimulatePhysics` in your `SKScene` subclass. The choice would depend on if you are just moving your character around by yourself in `update:`, or if it also gets moved around by running SKActions or by simulated physics.